# Is it possible to do long polling with XPages?

Tags: ajax, xpages, comet, lotus-domino, polling

The Title is really the question, can you do long polling with Domino XPages?  So that instead of constantly polling the server, the query just takes place again when the first one times out.

Comment: The XPage servlet engine doesn't support comet-like polling (e.g. WebSockets) out of the box, but one could theoretically use the "Threads and Jobs" approach (http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=Threads%20and%20Jobs) to implement long polling. Perhaps if you describe your intended use case, it would be easier to provide specific recommendations.

Comment: No specific requirement Tim, was just wondering if it was now possible.  Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to deploy your own Servlet to implement this. XPages being based on OSGi allows you to do that in form of a plugin with full access to the user session.